# Executing PE files in ASP.Net on Linux without using Mono

Tags: asp.net, mono

Can anyone tell me is it possible to executing '.exe' or '.dll' file(s) to run Asp.net on Linux server?

I know its possible with the use of Mono project.

But is it possible with the use of Mono Project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Mhh... NOT(really)
You can't execute natively exes on Linux only with Wine. I don't know if is gonna work running an asp.net server (IIS) on Linux with Wine.

Maybe you should get a try.

BTW: why not use Mono? Is it very good now. It has evolved much